# How to get a term from the translated term name?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a translated taxonomy term whose name is *Autos Y Motores* (Spanish). How can I get the taxonomy term object from it?

If the term name were in English, I would use `taxonomy_get_term_by_name('Vehicles & Motors')` to get the taxonomy term object.

How can I do with a translated taxonomy term name?

Comment: How is the term translated - manually thru a field or automatically thru a module like i18n?

Comment: Actually I have the translated string and if any way i am able to get actual string, i would be able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't find any function in Drupal which can translate the translated string into actual string. So, what I did was hit db to get the actual string and hence the string.

```
    $translated = 'Autos Y Motores';
    $query = db_select('locales_target', 'lt');
    $query
      ->condition('lt.translation', $target)
      ->fields('lt', array('translation'))
      ->fields('ls', array('source'))
      ->join('locales_source', 'ls', 'ls.lid=lt.lid');
    $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try to translate it before pass it to `taxonomy_get_term_by_name` function, try some thing like

```
$string= 'De Lema'; // string in not default site language I suppose in French
$default_lang_short = 'un'; // I supposes you default site language is english change it to your default
$en_value = t($string, array(), array('langcode' => $default_lang_short));
taxonomy_get_term_by_name($en_value);
```

Comment: I have 'Autos Y Motores' in a variable, and not Vehicles & Motors

Comment: @PurushotamRai it is just a example.

Comment: You are not getting me... The problem is i have translated string and i need actual string. The above code doesn't work.

Comment: @PurushotamRai I don't know your language, I just provide simple solution, first translate it default site  language ( I supposed your default language is english), then try to  `taxonomy_get_term_by_name`

Comment: @PurushotamRai check the answer again, I got you a clue not exact the solution, change your data with what you want !!!!

Comment: upon searching on drupal website, i found that t() cann't get us the original string and hence it's of no use in my case. Anyways, thanks a lot, i finally found a way to tackle the problem.

Comment: @PurushotamRai it can, I use this method several times, maybe you have mistake in using it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have this set:

- ES: *Autos Y Motores*
- EN: *Vehicles & Motors*

Use this code:

```
 $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('Autos Y Motores');
 //getting the term object
 $term = array_values($term)[0];
 //searching the translation
 $translated_term = i18n_taxonomy_term_get_translation($term, 'en');
 //$translated_term is your term in English
 echo $translated_term->name;
```

Output:

> Vehicles & Motors

Comment: the downvoter can explain where is the problem? I can improve my answer

Comment: Don't worry to much about anonymous downvotes ... It only takes 1 upvote to compensate for 5 downvotes ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens the problem is not the rep, is always learn form the mistakes

Comment: Maybe there was just no mistake, but some other whatever reason "just" to downvote ...